# Android Studio Gradle error: failed to resolve com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc2

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

In Android studio this dependency was working a month back, but now doesn't seem to work anymore.
Oddly using terminal ./gradlew I'm able to build. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this lib is ok on:

- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.auto.service/auto-service/1.0-rc2
- https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.google.auto.service%3Aauto-service/1.0-rc2/view

Did any changes affected your main build.gradle file? If not, try removing your .gradle folder and try again.